# Oracle ORDER BY not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to use Oracle's ORDER BY statement with the following query...

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHS
FROM     transaction_upload
WHERE    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY')
ORDER BY MONTHS;
```

The results that I'm getting however are:

```
MONTHS
-----------------
APR-2009
AUG-2009
DEC-2009
FEB-2009
JAN-2009
JUL-2009
JUN-2009
MAR-2009
MAY-2009
NOV-2009
OCT-2009
SEP-2009
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) could help

Comment: As the answers you got give you solutions but don't explain your error, I'll do it here: MONTHS is a string. You are sorting by that string, so you get your result records in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to order chronologically.

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHS
FROM     transaction_upload
WHERE    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY')
ORDER BY to_date (months,'MON-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, this will order Jan 09, Feb 09,

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTHS ,
to_Char(transaction_date,'YYYYMM')  NumMon
FROM     transaction_upload
WHERE    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'MON-YYYY'),to_Char(transaction_date,'YYYYMM') 
ORDER BY NumMon;
```